# lex an yacc getting differentiation value

Tags: yacc, lex

I am getting first order value for the $1 and $3 strings, but I am unable to add them both (concat)
For example:

```
Input:  sinx - cosx
Output: cosx + sinx
```

I am unable to get the output in this form.
My code is as follows:

lex code:

```
 %{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "y.tab.h"
 %}

 %%
 [ \t] ;
 [-+]  { return *yytext; }
 (s|c|t)..x  { yylval=strdup(yytext); return Str;}
 [a-zA-Z]+  { printf("Invalid");}

 %%

int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
```

yacc code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char* forder(char* a);
%}

%start exps
%token Str 

%% 
exps: exps exp 
| exp
;
exp : Str '+' Str {printf("%s\n",forder($1));
        printf("%s",forder($3));}
| Str '-' Str {printf("%s - %s",$1, $3); }
;
%%
struct symbol
{
char label[10];
char forder[10];
char sorder[10];
}res;

extern FILE *yyin; 


int main (void) 
{
printf("Enter Here:\n");
return yyparse();

}

yyerror(char *err) {
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",err);
}

char* forder(char* a){

FILE *s1;
yyin=s1;
yyin=fopen("C:/Users/pramo/Desktop/symbol.txt","r+");


            while(fscanf(yyin,"%s %s %s",res.label,res.forder,res.sorder)==3)
            {

    if(strcmp(res.label,a)==0){
                    //printf("\nFirst order derivative is:%s",res.forder);
                    break;
                }
            }
    return (res.forder);
    fclose(yyin);
  }
```

This is what I am getting:

```
Input:  sinx + cosx
Output: cosx - sinx
```

symbol.txt - I am storing the symbol table

Comment: @siavas: that edit obscures the output; I suspect that it does contain a newline, but who knows? Pram: Any input character which is not recognized by a lex rule is echied to stdout. In your case, that will include newlines (and possibly carriage returns). You should fix that by recognising all characters.

Comment: @rici, we can then highlight it with a quote styling. What do you think?

Comment: yes it contains new line in the output actually.

Comment: Anyways got it working.